# My html is not rendering but route is changing in react

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import indexRoutes from "routes/index";
import { loadHomeScripts } from './loadScriptsForHomePage';
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";



var hist = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    loadHomeScripts();
}

    render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
        <div class="fixed-custom">
        <nav id="top-bar-main" class="top-bar" data-topbar>

            <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="pull-right">


                <li class="has-dropdown">

                <Link to='/coaches'>
                Coaches
                </Link>
                </li>

                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>

                <li><a href="signin.html">Sign in</a></li>
                <li class="sign-up"><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
                    <li class="special-tariff-wrap" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
                        <a href="signup.html" alt="Every type of fitness class you can imagine. An ever-growing, diverse library of online workout videos for as low as $8.50 per month!" class="button header special-tariff">START YOUR FREE MONTH</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
        </div>


    <Router history={hist}>
        <Suspense fallback={<div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '0%', left: "18%" }}>
            <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/189524/screenshots/2822794/silhouette-solo-loader-dribbble_v2.gif" alt="loader"></img>
            </div>}>
        <Switch>
            {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return <Route exact path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />;
            })}
        </Switch>
        </Suspense>
    </Router>


</BrowserRouter>
    </div>
        )
    }
}


export default App;
```

routes - index.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = React.lazy(() => import('views/Home'));
const SignIn = React.lazy(() => import('views/SignIn'));
const SignUp = React.lazy(() => import('views/SignUp'));
const Workouts = React.lazy(() => import('views/Workouts'));
const WorkoutPlans = React.lazy(() => import('views/WorkoutPlans'));
const Topics = React.lazy(() => import('views/Topics'));
const Mom = React.lazy(() => import('views/Mom')); 
const Coaches = React.lazy(() => import('views/Coaches')); 
const CoachProfile = React.lazy(() => import('views/CoachProfile')); 
const Pricing = React.lazy(() => import('views/Pricing')); 

var indexRoutes = [
{ path: "/coachprofile", name: "CoachProfile", component: CoachProfile },
{ path: "/coaches", name: "Coaches", component: Coaches },
{ path: "/mom", name: "Mom", component: Mom },
{ path: "/topics", name: "Topics", component: Topics },
{ path: "/browse", name: "WorkoutPlans", component: WorkoutPlans },
{ path: "/workouts", name: "Workouts", component: Workouts },
{ path: "/signup", name: "SignUp", component: SignUp },
{ path: "/signin", name: "SignIn", component: SignIn },
{ path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

Coaches.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { loadHomeScripts } from 'utils/loadScriptsForHomePage';


class Coaches extends React.Component{

componentDidMount(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id = 'workout_plan_authors_index';
    loadHomeScripts();
}


    render(){
        return (
            <h1>coaches page</h1>

        )
    }
}

export default Coaches;
```

Here i am using router with **reactjs**.

I have one component named **Coaches.js**.

I have add  to **coaches**

when i am clicking on the coaches link in my website my url is changing
from **"http://localhost:3000/"**  to **"http://localhost:3000/coaches"** but html is
not changing it is showing same home Data.

But, when i am reloding the page again in **"http://localhost:3000/coaches"**
it is rendering the html.

Please have a look.

Comment: why do you have both `BrowserRouter` and `Router`?

Comment: fixed bro. Thanks

Comment: try to 

{  export const withRouter(Coaches)  }

and import it from react-router-dom